# Firefox locks places.sqlite

Tags: sqlite, firefox, apsw

Platform: Firefox 3.6.13, Python 2.7 stackless, and Windows 7 (not yet tested on Ubuntu, I will...)

I tried with the apsw library:

```
conn = apsw.Connection( dir + profile + '/places.sqlite', apsw.SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY )
```

And I got the error:

> File "c:\apsw\src\statementcache.c",
>   line 386, in sqlite3_prepare
>   apsw.BusyError: BusyError: database is
>   locked

I see "SQLite manager" can open the database also with Firefox running.

I just want to open and read, I think a trouble free operation. And I cannot use "SQLite manager". I need to code my Python (or PHP or Perl) script.

1) Which type of lock does Firefox use on the SQLite file? Why?

2) How does "SQLite manager" work?

---

Q2) SQLite Manager works in JavaScript, inside Firefox, so it can access the database.

This is not what I am looking for: An external application reading places while Firefox is running.

Comment: My hack is to copy places.sqlite to another file and open that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to open a locked sqlite database in read only mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857755/is-it-possible-to-open-a-locked-sqlite-database-in-read-only-mode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox uses SQLite to obtain an EXCLUSIVE lock on the database, which is why you cannot open it:
https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_locking_mode

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure about the lock type Firefox uses, but I'd recommend this:

Copy the Firefox database file to a different temporary location and read it from there (this also lowers the risk of accidentally damaging the original file).

I haven't had problems with this method yet on Firefox 3.*.

Comment: BTW, I've recently had problems with opening the places.sqlite of Firefox 4. It seems like reading it requires SQLite 3.7 which is not integrated into all 3rd party language wrappers yet (older versions get a "db is encrypted" error). So keep an eye out for this problem, too.

Comment: Thanks to your hint I got sqlite 3.7 running with Firefox 4.0 places.sqlite. But I'm looking for the ADO.NET solution and sqlite-dotnet-x86-1006900.exe doesn't work with PowerShell (possibly a debug build)

Comment: i am finding that when it try read from the database (d copied history), sometimes it is not updated.. :/ it seems to remain locked