# Opening Firefox file 'places.sqlite' with PowerShell and System.Data.SQLite

Tags: sqlite, powershell, ado.net

I want to run the following code:

```
$dll = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data.SQLite")
# [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files\System.Data.SQLite\bin\System.Data.SQLite.dll")

$ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\Var\sqlite_ff4\places.sqlite"

$conn = New-Object System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
$conn.Open()
$sql = "SELECT * from moz_bookmarks"
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand($sql, $conn)

#    $cmd.CommandTimeout = $timeout

$ds = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
$da = New-Object System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter($cmd)
$da.fill($ds)

$conn.close()

$ds.tables[0]
```

At the line

```
$conn.Open()
```

I get the error

```
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "File opened that is not a database file
file is encrypted or is not a database"
At line:5 char:11
+ $conn.Open <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

The file `places.sqlite` is from Firefox 4.0. I'm using http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/.

**EDIT:**

The above works for the Firefox 3.0 file `places.sqlite`. Something seems to be different with Firefox 4.0.

It doesn't seem to be a password problem, but a version problem. Thanks to [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706537/firefox-locks-places-sqlite/4804466#4804466) I found, that I need SQLite 3.7.

I hope I find some current ADO provider.

sqlite-dotnet-x86-1006900.exe from [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) doesn't work

Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Inte
rop.DLL': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8
007007E)"

It is possibly a debug build. Are there any prebuild version without an SQLite.Interop.DLL?

Comment: Can you open this database by any other SQLite tool, e.g. sqlite3.exe command line utility (see the official site downloads)?

Comment: I can open it with the SQLite Manager Firefox Addon

Comment: With sqlite3.exe places.sqlite I get :Error: file is encrypted or is not a database

Comment: Just a guess: it might be password protected. If this is the case you need to get it and specify in the connection string `Data Source=...; Password=...`.

Answer (score 1):

**Finally solved (by work around of not installing in GAC):**

To open Firefox 4.0 places.sqlite you must use a version 3.7 or upper from sqlite.

I installed sqlite-dotnet-x86-1007000.exe  from [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki), but did **not** check the install in GAC checkbox. Install in GAC is still faulty.

Now the following PowerShell Code works fine on a copy of places.sqlite (remember you can't open it while locked by Firefox):

```
# adapt these two lines to your loacal system
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files\System.Data.SQLite\bin\System.Data.SQLite.dll") 
$ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\Var\sqlite_ff4\places.sqlite"

$conn=new-object System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection 
$conn.ConnectionString=$ConnectionString 
$conn.Open() 
$sql = "SELECT * from moz_bookmarks"
$cmd=new-object System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand($sql,$conn)
$ds=New-Object system.Data.DataSet
$da=New-Object System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter($cmd)
$da.fill($ds) 
$conn.close()
$ds.tables[0]
```

Since sqlite-dotnet-x86-1006900.exe they spitted SQLite.Interop.dll from System.Data.SQLite.dll, but had problems with installing it in GAC. If you check the install in GAC checkbox, you get an
Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.DLL
error. There is a closed [ticket](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview?name=54e52d4c6f) for this error, but I think it is not fixed. The ticket is reopened again. check there for new work arounds or solutions.

Comment: Did you check the option "GAC" on installation? Try to do this and then use the workaround (it was me BTW who posted that, so I did try this, it worked for me).

Comment: Yes I tried it. The other dllS go to C:\Windows\assembly, but SQLite.Interop.dll is missing. Going back to the old version to develop my scripts until there is a fixed precompiled version. I don't want to spend time compiling it myself.