# Is it possible to open a locked sqlite database in read only mode?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'd like to open the chromium site data (in ~/.config/chromium/Default) with python-sqlite3 but it gets locked whenever chromium is running, which is understandable since transactions may be made. Is there a way to open it in read-only mode, ensuring that I can't corrupt the integrity of the db while chromium is using it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it depends on the lock set by the transaction.

https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html#shared_lock
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html

SQLite exclusive transactions lock both read and write where immediate and deferred transactions will still allow readers.

So it really depends on the transactions used by Chromium.

Answer (score 11):

It seems we can bypass the lock by opening the database in `immutable` mode, e.g.:

```
sqlite3 'file:places.sqlite?immutable=1'
```

As explained here https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html

This can cause querying errors if the underlying database file changes, or obviously not seeing updates that are made to the file, but I found that re-opening the connection on each new query helps with that.

To achieve the same thing with most SQLite drivers, because we can't directly set [`SQLITE_IOCAP_IMMUTABLE`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_iocap_atomic.html), the best way is to open the connection with the flag `SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY | SQLITE_OPEN_URI` to allow passing the `file:...?immutable=1` URI as `filename`.

Comment: Nice! `echo "SELECT ..." | sqlite3 'file:///home/my_user/.mozilla/firefox/12wh3gmq.work/cookies.sqlite?immutable=1'` worked for me! Other ways of `sqllite3 -readonly ...` or `sqlite3 ...?mode=ro` were not helping. Also `sqlite3 'file://~/.mozilla/firefox/12wh3gmq.work/cookies.sqlite?immutable=1'` is not working.

Answer (score 7):

Chromium is holding a database lock for long periods of time? Yuck! That's really not a very good idea at all. Still, not *your* fault…

You could try just copying the database file (e.g., with the system utility `cp`) and using that snapshot for reading purposes; SQLite keeps all its committed state in a single file per database. Yes, there's a chance of seeing a partial transaction, but you will definitely not have lock problems on Unix as SQLite definitely doesn't use mandatory locks. (This might well not work on Windows due to the different locking scheme there.)

Comment: It's not necessarily chromium's fault. Snooping around, I found [this](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-July/1211171.html) helpful message that pointed out that the pysqlite library doesn't provide an interface to all of sqlite's features because it's DB-API compliant. So it could be that when I open the db with pysqlite, I'm doing so without say in read-write mode. He pointed to APSW to use the SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY flag when starting a connection. I'll check it out now.

Comment: This is the workaround I used, because I got lost in like 15 browser tabs trying to figure out the "correct" solution for concurrent access to Firefox's `places.sqlite`. It's the same deal with Firefox, same error message. Just alter your program to work on a copy and enjoy more of your life, without worrying about `PRAGMA main.journal_mode=WAL`s and `SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY`s and poring over the C API documentation, only to find out you can't do this or that with Python's `sqlite3` library.